# Reading two consecutive writes from a FIFO using select() and O_NONBLOCK

Tags: c, select, named-pipes, nonblocking, fifo

I'm trying to write two consecutive strings. The issue is that the reader keeps greeting EAGAIN when using `O_NONBLOCK` on the reader.

Any ideas why it doesn't work when using O_NONBLOCK, shouldn't `select()` take care of the block?

**reader.c**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);

    write(fd, "12345678", strlen("12345678"));
    write(fd, "HelloWorld", strlen("HelloWorld"));
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

**writer.c**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char buf[BUFSIZ] = { 0 }, buf2[BUFSIZ] = { 0 };
int read1 = 0, read2 = 0;

int main() {
    int fd = 0, a = 0, b = 0 ; 
    char *myfifo= "/tmp/myfifo";

    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
    fd_set set;

    if ((fd = open(myfifo, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0)
        exit(1);

    while (1) {
        FD_ZERO(&set);
        FD_SET(fd, &set);

        if ((select(fd+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL)) < 1)
            exit(1);

        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &set)) {
            int total = 0;

            if ((total = read(fd, buf + read1, sizeof(uint32_t) * 2) - read1) <= 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
                continue;
            }   
            read1 += total;

            if ((total = read(fd, buf2 + read2, BUFSIZ - read2)) <= 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
                continue;
            }   
            read2 += total;

            fprintf(stderr, "%s %d, %d, %s\n", buf, a, b, buf2);
            memset(buf, 0, BUFSIZ);
            memset(buf2, 0, BUFSIZ);
            read1 = read2 = 0;
        }   
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Linux man page for "open"  says the following about using O_RDWR on a fifo:  " O_RDWR Open for reading and writing. The result is undefined if this flag is applied to a FIFO."

Comment: On Linux it is ok, see man page for `fifo`: Under  Linux,  opening  a FIFO for read and write will succeed both in blocking and nonblocking mode.  POSIX leaves this behavior undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `read` on the fd twice in the loop, it is possible that the first `read` read the data available, and the second `read` will fail with `EAGAIN`.
You should test the readiness with select before performing any `read`, not just the first one. Because fifos are streams, that means, you have to maintain your own boundary of different pieces of data.

```
char buf[BUFSIZ];
if (FD_ISSET(fd, &set)) {
    int total = 0;
    int off = 0;
    total = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf);
    if (total <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
            continue;
    }
    // retrieve the data based on how many bytes you have read
    if (total >= sizeof(uint32_t) * 2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, it's recommended to open with `O_RDONLY` for the read end, and `O_WRONLY` for the writing end of the fifo.

Comment: Thanks. From what I understand, I should be able to read `n` amount of bytes on the first read, and `n` amount on the second read? From your example, it seems I should be reading the whole size of the buffer in one read?

Comment: Also, I believe `select()` won't stop being 'active' if `O_RDONLY` is used due to the `EOF`, thus I have to use `O_RDWR`.

Comment: @PeteDarrow But it's not guaranteed that you can read out n bytes on the first read, you might be read less than that. As I said, there is no boundaries in streams, what you write in a block does not necceassily read as one block.

Comment: I agree, however, I think passing `buf + read1, sizeof(uint32_t) * 2) - read1` should cover the case where it needs to read the left over, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: By using nonblocking IO, any time you read, you should expect the amount of data you read is less that the amount you want to read.